# Suppose we have a non-zero non unit $r$ in $R$ that cannot be written as a product of irreducibles ...

Tags: ring-theory

Problem: Let $R$ be an integral domain. Suppose we have a non-zero non-unit $r$ in $R$ that cannot be written as a product of irreducibles, then my textbook states without proof that $r$ is "certainly not irreducible".

I'm not sure why this is true. If $r=ab$ then consider two cases:

1) $a,b$ are both reducible, in this case I have to show that $r=ab$ implies that both $a,b$ are non-units (I think). Not sure how to proceed

2) The case where $a$ is reducible, and $b$ is not (or vice versa).

I am very confused right now and I think that I am missing something basic. Insights appreciated.

My definition of irreducible is : An element $p \in R$ is irreducible if $p \neq 0$, $p$ is not a unit, and if $p=ab$ then either $a$ or $b$ is a unit. If an element does not satisfy this definition it is reducible.

This comes from the chapter "5.1: Irreducibles and Unique Factorization" from Nicholson's introduction to Abstract Algebra 4th edition page 255.

Comment: I guess you mean $r$ is irreducible? Otherwise consider $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. Maybe you can tell us, what your definition of reducibility is? I am sure that this would help you to answer your own question.

Comment: The statement as written is obviously false.  Are you sure you have copied it correctly?

Comment: @EricWofsey I think I have copied it correctly, but I will post a screenshot to make sure.

Comment: The last edit you made (removing the word "two") makes a huge difference in the meaning!

Comment: @EricWofsey does the author consider a single element a "product" then? I didn't think this mattered, but now I believe I have the correct statement. My mistake.

Comment: @IntegrateThis Yes, that is standard, and an empty product $= 1\ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that "product of irreducibles" means "product of any number of irreducibles", not necessarily a binary product.  So an irreducible element $r$ can always be written as a product of irreducibles, namely a unary product consisting just of $r$.

Comment: Oh. Well now I'm embarassed, oh well better to have done this now then on a test or something.

Comment: It would have been better to answer this in a comment so that the OP could delete the question (which is surely a dupe)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the issue is that the author is using a different definition of product than you are.

A fairly standard definition is something like the following:

Let $n$ be a natural number, regarded as an ordinal, so $n=\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$. Let $s:n\to A$ be a map to a ring (or more generally a monoid).

Then we define $\prod_{i\in n} s_i$, usually written as $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} s_n$ recursively by $$\prod_{i\in 0} s_i =1,$$ and $$\prod_{i\in k+1} s_i = \left(\prod_{i\in k} s_i\right)\cdot s_k.$$

Note that this definition gives meaning to the notion of the empty and unary products.